# Does NitrousIO support RBENV?

Tags: rbenv, nitrousio

With Nitrous.io the documentation states that other Ruby version managers may be used instead of RVM.

However, sudo is needed for installing rbenv

Is RVM currently the only option on nitrous.io?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not wish to use RVM which is pre-installed then you can install rbenv. Run the following commands within your [Nitrous.IO](https://www.nitrous.io) console:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

These steps can be found within the [Octopress guide](http://andrijac.github.io/blog/2013/12/21/octopress-publishing-environment-in-the-cloud/) which utilizes rbenv on [Nitrous.IO](https://www.nitrous.io).

Comment: I've tried this but get a bash error "rbenv: command not found". After checking, `~/.rbenv` doesn't actually exist even though I cloned it as you've written here, with no errors. Any ideas why??